# Short name for SDE featureclass?

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase

Is there an ArcObjects function to get a short name version of an SDE featureclass?

For example if my featureclass is:

FOOSCHEMA.BARLAYER

How do I just get "BARLAYER".

Or is it just a simple case of using string manipulation techniques with your language of choice?

BTW - This is an ArcEngine app.

Comment: Why not use IFeatureclass.AliasName? Its purpose is to provide a user friendly name.  It is editable via IClassSchemaEdit.

Comment: I think you have to edit that yourself though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the sde workspace to ISqlSyntax and use the ParseTableName function.

Comment: Brilliant - I don't think I would ever have found that.

Answer (score 1):

Got LINQ? Just stick a `.Split('.').Last()` on your property or variable that has the featureclass name.

```
featureClassName.Split('.').Last()
```